# MySql DataReader : reading multiple records

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, wpf

I am trying to select the rows that the field = `Title` includes same keywords. My table has 2 rows that the `Title` fields are **Sweet Country** & **Sweet Country 2**. I do a query and select the rows including `Sweet` at their `Title` field.

I store the data of the first row in a list but I don't know how should I change the cursor to the second record with MySqlDataReader!

Here is my code:

```
DB.dbConnection.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from Movies where Title LIKE '%" + searchKeyword + "%'",DB.dbConnection);
            DB.dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (DB.dataReader.Read())
            {
                baseResponse.response = true;
                baseResponse.search.Add(new Movie.Item
                {
                    title = DB.dataReader.GetString(1),
                    year = DB.dataReader.GetString(2),
                    released = DB.dataReader.GetString(3),
                    runTime = DB.dataReader.GetString(4),
                    genre = DB.dataReader.GetString(5),
                    director = DB.dataReader.GetString(6),
                    writer = DB.dataReader.GetString(7),
                    actors = DB.dataReader.GetString(8),
                    language = DB.dataReader.GetString(9),
                    country = DB.dataReader.GetString(10),
                    awards = DB.dataReader.GetString(11),
                    poster = DB.dataReader.GetString(12),
                    imdbScore = DB.dataReader.GetString(13),
                    production = DB.dataReader.GetString(14),
                    dl480p = DB.dataReader.GetString(15),
                    dl720p = DB.dataReader.GetString(16),
                    dl1080p = DB.dataReader.GetString(17),
                    subtitleLink = DB.dataReader.GetString(18),
                    dubLink = DB.dataReader.GetString(19),
                    description = DB.dataReader.GetString(20),
                    state = DB.dataReader.GetString(21),
                });
}
```

This script, just reads the first record! How can I get the second record that the query has returned?!

Comment: your code seems fine

Comment: @Bizhan: but it returns only one list! Why?

Comment: I would tell you if I were a wizard! check your code again and debug it carefully

Comment: @Bizhan: it's about 2 days, That I am debugging and taking the note of variables' values, but again I cannot get to anything!

Comment: @Bizhan: the Read() method only reads the first record! can you please specify can I use any methods like NextResult? if yes, Where?

Comment: Read method will automatically move to the next record. so it's not that. here's some hint: change `DB.dataReader` to `var reader`, change `baseResponse.search.Add` to `var item` and see what happens

Comment: @Bizhan: didn't work :(

Comment: have you tried the query in the sql management studio? does it actually return more than one row?

Comment: @Bizhan: Yes, and I get exactly 2 rows

Comment: I got nothing else... your code is completely correct.

Comment: @Bizhan: that's exactly the point, it's correct but it doesn't work!

Comment: if you are 100% sure about all the above statements and you have debugged your code line by line, then I would suggest you ask a friend to look at your project. stackoverflow does not debug your code.

Comment: @Bizhan: Thanks a lot for answering